# What are the risks of using data:image/jpeg;base64?

Tags: php, base64, jpeg

I am using a TinyMCE text editor in a custom CMS and I drag images into the textarea and then align them. They are given a data:image/jpeg;base64 value and they show up perfect in the user area. But what are the risks with doing this? Do these images render in all browsers? I guess there are some SEO issues to take in to account but It seems like it would be a better system having them stored in the DB rather than folders.

What do you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- IE7 and earlier don't support `data:` URLs at all.
- IE8 doesn't support `data:` URLs longer than 32 KB. (Are you sensing a trend here?)
- Base64 encoded images are about 30% larger than if you stored them raw.
- If you reuse images in multiple documents, you end up with multiple copies. If you stored them as files, you'd be able to reference the same file in each location.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe is the worst idea. The size of images are different and some are smaller, some are quite large.
The larger the image is the harder will be for the browser to render it. The longer the HTML code will be the harder for the browser will be to render.
The browser can freeze for a very large amount of time and that is annoying.

It's best you save the images as files.